# Trying to use express middleware to serve third party API requests

Tags: express, cors, axios

Sorry if I posted this incorretly, it is my first question on Stack Overflow. I am currently trying to use express to serve third party API requests to my React front-end. This is because the steam api I use throws me a CORS error when requesting in the client-side. I tried to route the requests to my controller which makes the axios call, but I have had no luck. Not sure if I am doing something completely incorrect.

here is my server.js

```
    const app = require('./app.js');

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;

    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`))
```

and here is my app.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors')
    const app = express();

    app.use(cors())
    module.exports = app
```

my routes:

```
    const { Router } = require('express')
    const controllers = require('../controllers')
    const router = Router()

    router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('This is root!'))

    router.get('/applist', controllers.getAllSteamGames)
    router.get('/game/:id', controllers.getSingleGameSteam )

    router.get('/gameSpy/:id', controllers.getSingleGameSpy)


    module.exports = router
```

and lastly my controller:

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    const getAllSteamGames = async () => {
        try {

        const resp = await axios.get('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2?applist')
        return resp.data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything to send a response back to the client.  If we look at the `/applist` route:

```
router.get('/applist', controllers.getAllSteamGames)

const axios = require('axios');
const getAllSteamGames = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2?applist');
        return resp.data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw error
    }
}
```

All, your `getAllSteamGames()` function does is return a promise that resolves to a value (remember all `async` functions return a promise).  It doesn't send a response back to the client.

Then, if you look  at the actual route handler, it doesn't send a response back to the  client either.  So, you get the request and never send a response.  The client never gets a response.

What I would suggest is that you just send a response in your controller.  It's already passed `(req, res)` as arguments to the function so you can use them.

```
router.get('/applist', controllers.getAllSteamGames)

const axios = require('axios');
const getAllSteamGames = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2?applist');
        res.json(resp.data);
    } catch (error) {
        // send error status upon error
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying. I thought you could return the response from the axios call and it implicitly was a response for the controller. I will try that fix out, thank you for your help.

Comment: @philipryan - Your controller is just a plain Javascript object that you presumably picked up as an code suggestion.  It has no special powers at all - it's just a way of organizing request handler functions.  Something in your code has to return the response.  If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: Update: 
Yes! It worked, thank you very much. I was getting a type error for trying to convert a circular structure into json. I changed resp to resp.data and it worked.